# How to extract substrings from a variable?

Tags: apache, variables, substring, server-side-includes

I want to echo out the three-digit HTTP error code into three separate digits. I tried two methods, but both failed to work:

**Method 1**

```
<!--#echo var="{$REDIRECT_STATUS,0,1}" --><br>
<!--#echo var="{$REDIRECT_STATUS,1,1}" --><br>
<!--#echo var="{$REDIRECT_STATUS,2,1}" -->
```

Output:

(none)
(none)
(none)

**Method 2**

```
<!--#if expr="$REDIRECT_STATUS = /^([0-9]{1})([0-9]{1})([0-9]{1})$/" -->
<!--#echo var="$1" --><br>
<!--#echo var="$2" --><br>
<!--#echo var="$3" -->
```

Output:

(none)
404
(none)

**What I want is:**

4
0
4

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.